# preg_replace pattern for textarea

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I simply wanna allow only this characters (theese inside quotation marks) "a-z0-9.?!-_ "  (last character is space). There is my code, but there must be something wrong. I tried to check documentation, but I'm lost.

```
$output = preg_replace('/![a-z0-9.!?-_ ]/i', '', $_POST['textarea']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To negate a character class, do this:

```
[^a-z0-9.!?_ -]
```

What you have (the `!` before it) is not how you negate it. Also note that `-` should either be escaped, or moved to the end of the character class otherwise it has a special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you negate a character class. Use the caret symbol (`^`) instead.

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9.!?_ -]/i', '', $_POST['textarea']);
```

The hyphen, when used inside a character class indicates a range unless it is the last character in the class, first character in the class, or directly after the opening negating caret (`^`). In the above regex, I have changed the position of the hyphen to the last, however, I recommend escaping it using a backslash (`\^`) for clarity purposes.